# How many students were there if a total of 870 photographs were exchanged

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

After the graduation exercises at school, the students exchanged photographs with each others. How many students were there if a total of $870$ photographs were exchanged ?

My attempt:

I used the combination formula $^nC_r$  where $n = 870$ and $r=2$ .

But my answer seems to be wrong.

Where i am wrong?

Comment: Hint: Count two exchanged photographs, for each pair of students.

Comment: Also, instead of $n=870$ you should search for $n$ as the unknown.

Comment: I am sorry , i am not understanding both your hints . Can please elaborate

Comment: 1) @HagenvonEitzen's hint: Let $n$ be the number of students. 2) Derive a formula for the number of pairs of students. 3) My hint: Derive a formula for the number of photographs 4) You know, that this number should equal 870, so try to find $n$.

Comment: okay , Total pairs of student is $2$ & number of photographs are $870$. So again $nCr$

Comment: No, the total number of pairs of students is not $2$. There are $n$ many students, i.e. you don't know exactly how many. Why should there be only two pairs of students? If $n=2$, I count one pair, if $n=3$, I count three pairs. Think about step 2) again.

Comment: I am confused now! Can you please explain complete problem so i can solve similar further questions.

Comment: Okay, let's do step 2). The number of pairs of students is $\binom{n}{2}$ or $nC2$ in your notation. Can you continue now with step 3)?

Comment: Let $n$ be the number of students. Every student gives a photograph to $n-1$ students. Total number of photographs is $n(n-1)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning.

We know $870$ photographs were shared. If $n$ is the number of students (which is what we want to solve for), then we know each student gives a photograph to every *other* student: each of the $n$ students gives a photo to $n - 1$ students. So the total number of photographs is $$\begin{align} n(n - 1) & = 870\tag{$\dagger$}\\ \\ n^2 - n - 870 & = 0 \\ \\ (n-30)(n+29) & = 0 \\ \\ \iff n = 30 \;& \text{or} \; n = -29\end{align}$$ We are needing a *positive* number of students here, so we take $n = 30$.

Therefore, there are $\;30\;$ graduating students here, each of whom gives a photograph to $n - 1 = 29$ *other* students: $30\times 29 = 870 $ photographs exchanged.

This would be the same result if we computed the number of students for whom $\bf 2$ photographs were exchanged for every **pair** of $n$ students: Again: $n$ is our unknown number of students, $\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of *pairs* of students: $$\begin{align} 2 \times \binom{n}{2} & = 870 \\ \\ 2\times \frac{n!}{2! \,(n - 2)!} & = 870 \\ \\ 2\times \frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2} & = 870 \\ \\ n(n-1) & = 870...\tag{see $\dagger$}\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow man thanks nice explanation

Comment: $n^2-n-870$ you used quadratic equation formula to solve ?

Comment: I simply figured out the factors, since I knew they must be integers (we can't have a fraction of a person!): $30 \cdot 30 = 900,$ so $29\cdot 30 = 900 - 30 = 870$. But the quadratic formula would work as well.